# Returned parameter displays object Object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to create a function that will take a provided parameter and make that item `sticky` instead of `fixed` (for a banner). I noticed whenever I take in my parameter it only displays as `object Object` and I can't seem to convert it.

Here is the code in question:

```
$(function() {
    var containerIdName = 'div#stickyRemoval';
    $(window).scroll(function(
        var newContainerIdName = containerIdName;

        alert(newContainerIdName);

        var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
        var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();

        if ((scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight === 0) {
            $(newContainerIdName).css({position: 'sticky'});
        } else {
            $(newContainerIdName).css({position: 'fixed'});
        }
    });
});
```

I've put in a default variable for you to see, but in reality will be taking it in through a CMS. How can I convert that so my `newContainerIdName` variable shows up as a string instead of `object Object`?

Thanks in advance!

P.S https://codepen.io/robert9111/pen/BveGaQ as an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because you can't pass arguments to event handlers. The variable you're referencing in the `scroll` handler is actually the Event object which has been raised - which is why you see `[Object object]` when you coerce it to a string.

To do what you require, just remove the argument from the handler function. Also note the preferred used of classes to amend the styling in the example below:

```js
$(function() {
  var containerIdName = 'div#stickyRemoval';

  $(window).scroll(function() { // remove the argument here
    var scrollHeight = $(document).height();
    var scrollPosition = $(window).height() + $(window).scrollTop();
    var calc = (scrollHeight - scrollPosition) / scrollHeight;
    $(containerIdName).toggleClass('sticky', calc === 0).toggleClass('fixed', calc !== 0);
  });
});
```

```css
.sticky { position: sticky; }
.fixed { position: fixed; }
```

Comment: Many thanks, that makes more sense. Appreciate the great explanation!